# Drawing one more element in a D3 legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I try to plot the legend with D3 in my graph it draws one more element in the legend. And the console tells me this error message:

> poly1.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
>       at SVGGElement. (poly1.js:83)
>       at pt.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
>       at mycanvas (poly1.js:77)
>       at main (poly1.js:96)

This is  the javascript code:

```
var x = d3.range(-2., 2.1, 0.1)

myfunction = x => Math.pow(x, 3) - 1

var y = new Array()
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
    y[i] = myfunction(x[i])
}
var dataset = []
for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    dataset[j] = []
    dataset[j][0] = x[j]
    dataset[j][1] = y[j]
}

var w = 500
var h = 500
var padding = 50

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([d3.min(x, function(d) { return d }), d3.max(x, function(d) { return d })])
            .range([padding, w - padding])

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
             .domain([-10, 8])
             .range([h - padding, padding])

var color_hash = {0 : ["f(x)", "blue"]}
/*var color_hash = {  0 : ["f(x)", "blue"],
                        1 : ["mango", "orange"],
                        2 : ["cherry", "red"]
                      }*/

function mycanvas() {
    var svg = d3.select('.myfunction')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h)
    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('width', '100%')
        .attr('height', '100%')
        .style('fill', '#ffcc99')

    // Define the axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale).ticks(9)
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale).ticks(9)

    // Create the axis
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
        .call(xAxis)
    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ', 0)')
        .call(yAxis)

    // Define and plotting the function
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[0])})
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[1])})

    svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', line(dataset))
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('fill', 'none')

    //--------- THE LEGEND ------
    var legend = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("x", w)
      .attr("y", 25)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 100)
    legend.selectAll('g').data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .each(function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).append("rect")
          .attr("x", w - 400)
          .attr("y", i * 25 + 20)
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .style("fill", color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1])

         d3.select(this).append("text")
          .attr("x", w - 385)
          .attr("y", i * 25 + 30)
          .attr("height",30)
          .attr("width",100)
          .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1])
          .text(color_hash[String(i)][0])
    })
}

function main() {
    mycanvas()
}

window.onload = main
```

I'm using v4 with D3

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to unpack, but the problem is here:

```
color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1]
```

In the first iteration `indexOf(d)` is `0`. `color_hash[0]` is defined and so there is no problem. In the second iteration `indexOf(d)` is `1`. Since color_hash is defined as:

```
var color_hash = {0 : ["f(x)", "blue"]}
```

`color_hash[1]` is undefined so `color_hash[1][1]` is an error.

It looks like you have a larger color hash defined and commented out with more values. If you uncomment this, you'll get two more legend items until you get an error when `indexOf(d)` is `3`. It looks like you have 40 items in your data, which means you'd need a hash with 40 colors for this scheme to work. So I suspect, this is not what you are trying to do. If you let us know what you are expecting to happen, someone might be able to give more advice.